# how to keep laravel livewire wire:submit.prevent from reloading the page

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a pretty simple livewire component that helps a user store a vanity URL

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <span>{{ config('app.url') }}/request/</span>
            <input type="text" id="vanity" wire:model.defer="vanityUrl" name="vanityUrl">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@if($saved) Saved @else Save @endif</button>
            <button type="button" id="copy-vanity" class="btn btn-secondary">Copy</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the save action is pretty simple as well.

```
public function save()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->validate();
        $user->update(['vanity_slug' => Str::slug($this->vanityUrl)]);
        $this->vanityUrl = Str::slug($this->vanityUrl);
        $this->saved = true;
    }
```

This works locally but not in production.  I am using Forge, php7.4, L8, its all the same between the environments except the URLs.  I have livewire:scripts and livewire:styles loaded, and again it works locally but not in prod.

In prod, the page reloads.  I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days now... driving me crazy.  TIA

Comment: It's a typical issue after deployment - ensure Livewire is actually installed and run `php artisan optimize`

Comment: I tried that as well as PHP artisan optimize. Neither resolved the issue.

Livewire is installed and linked, the script loads just fine. That is why this is so confounding. I do have Alpine 3 loaded but I that shouldn't be causing this.

The form element gets a wire:id, wire:initial-data, and the wire:prevent.submit.

Comment: If you have Alpine.js v3, you need Livewire 2.5 or higher. The only solution I have heard working when a clear didn't work, is to reinstall Livewire in your production environment- in that case, it wasn't installed properly

Comment: @qirel that was the issue. Thank you.  Put that in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Cached Views

The most typical issue when Livewire isn't working after deploying to a production environment (or for that matter, after setting it up in localhost as well), is that your views, specifically `layouts/app.blade.php` is cached before the `@livewireScripts` directive is loaded. This means that it will not render `@livewireScripts` or `@livewireStyles` as the component, but will output the literal string.

This is fixed by simply running `php artisan optimize:clear`, to clear your cache (specifically the view cahce).

#### Missing Installation of Livewire

However, there are some cases where Livewire is not installed - or not installed properly. You can ensure that Livewire is installed through composer by running `composer show -D` while in the root directory of your Laravel application. Look for `livewire/livewire`. If its not there, then install it (see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation). To install Livewire through composer, run the following command.

```
composer require livewire/livewire
```

#### Using Alpine.js v3 and Livewire v2w

If you have updated to Apline.js v3, you need to use Livewire v2.5 or higher. Simply update your Livewire version.

#### Faulty Installation of Livewire

The last scenario I've heard of so far with this kind of problem, is that Livewire is installed - but its still not working properly. This is the most uncommon from what I have seen so far. This happens when the scripts that Livewire hooks into is not working as intended (say, a form with `wire:submit.prevent="submit"` is submitting the actual form instead of sending the AJAX request), but Livewire is installed and `@livewireScrtips` is rendering as it should. For whatever reason this happens, I'm not sure (as I haven't experienced it first hand), but its quite simple to fix.

The solution for these scenarios is to reinstall Livewire - and you do that by simply removing and require the package again. After the reinstall, its a good idea to clear the cache, just to ensure that the view is not cached without the Livewire-directives.

```
composer remove livewire/livewire && composer require livewire/livewire && php artisan optimize:clear
```